# Cannot create dataproc cluster

Tags: google-cloud-dataproc

When creating DataProc cluster using Web Console or `gcloud`, getting the same error:

```
gcloud dataproc --region us-west1 clusters create cluster-02eb --subnet default --zone us-west1-a --master-machine-type n1-standard-4 --master-boot-disk-size 500 --num-workers 2 --worker-machine-type n1-standard-4 --worker-boot-disk-size 500 --image-version 1.2 --scopes 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform' --project projectxyz123 --initialization-actions 'gs://dataproc-initialization-actions/jupyter/jupyter.sh'

Waiting on operation [projects/projectxyz123/regions/us-west1/operations/53badbbc-41cc-4241-aedb-490981864bf9].
Waiting for cluster creation operation...done.
ERROR: (gcloud.dataproc.clusters.create) Operation [projects/projectxyz123/regions/us-west1/operations/53badbbc-41cc-4241-aedb-490981864bf9] failed: com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 404 Not Found
Not Found.
```

What does this error means ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is currently a known issue for zone us-west1-a. Using an alternative zone should work (e.g. us-west1-b).